# rails compact array and NilClass

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

- I have a **Client** model with a Date field: `last_issue`
- A Client **has_many :tickets** and a **Ticket** has a Date field: `invoice_date`
- A Client **has_many :adverts** and an **Advert** has a Date field: `issue_date`

I am trying to use array with **compact** to find and present the **max date** from these 3 items in the Client show view, but am getting errors when the Client does not have a Ticket or an Advert.

When I try to display the max date in my view using:
`[@client.last_issue, @client.adverts.max.issue_date, @client.tickets.max.invoice_date].compact.max`
it fails whenever a Client is missing one of the associated models.

I know that compact will remove nil elements, but I am struck on the cleanest way to deal with the missing values from the Nil associations that lead to errors such as  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'issue_date' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: what `@client.adverts.max.issue_date` should return?

Comment: A Date value if the Client has any adverts. Before I tried to pull in the max from 3 dates, I would do something like  `<%= "last run: #{@client.adverts.max.issue_date.strftime("%b-%-d, %Y")}" if @client.adverts.any? %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description you only want to show the maximum date from the three types of object client.last_issue, client.adverts and client.tickets. Then save your app ressources and do not instantiate the tickets and adverts.
Instead load the plain maximum dates by using aggregation like:

```
[
 @client.last_issue, 
 @client.adverts.maximum(:issue_date),
 @client.tickets.maximum(:invoice_date)
].compact.max
```

You certanly want to move that snippet into a decorator.
Besides I'm not sure if actually meant to expect the minimum date (means the oldest), although you asked for maximum.

Comment: I meant for the most recent date (maximum) of the three. Thanks for helping adjust to remove use of try and for using maximum vs. max.

Answer (score 1):

As a one off thing you could do this.

```
[@client.try(:last_issue), @client.try(:adverts).try(:max).try(:issue_date), @client.try(:tickets).try(:max).try(:invoice_date)].compact.try(:max)
```

Have you considered implementing this so that you aren't reaching so deep into the other objects?  So that you only have to do 1 message to client for max invoice and issue date?

Comment: Any nil for @client.last_issue is taken care of by compact but I get back 'nil' when as short as this [@client.last_issue, @client.adverts.max.try(:issue_date), @client.tickets.max.try(:invoice_date)].compact.max. I do need to reach into each of the 3 models to compare the max, max dates in an array. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianRolle agreed, but is a quick fix

Comment: @memoht you do have to reach in, but you can do something like client.max_invoice_date and then have that call go in to get the date.  Then you can refactor that thing to be a delegated call to object that has knowledge of how to find the max date.

Comment: @Austio but why instantiating the objects at all and sorting afterwards? Why not letting the database doing the aggregating work and saving instantiation time (which is a lot!)?

Comment: I agree try is a code smell. I need something that isn't a quick fix as this particular Date is viewed quite often by end users. I also agree I need to refactor this... alas I need more skills.